# EF: Wrong relations when calling from partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to implement home made Banner system which logs views and clicks. Well almost everything works, except when I open a page and RenderBanners() action gets called from a partial view. It gets called as following:

_Layout.cshtml calls _Header.cshtml via `@Html.Partial("_Header")`, then in _Header.cshtml I call this action via `@{ Html.RenderAction("RenderBanners", "Home"); }`.

RenderBanners action:

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult RenderBanners()
        {
            var banners = bannerTimeRepository.ForcefulGetAll().ToList();  

            try
            {
                foreach(var banner in banners)
                {
                    bannerLogRepository.SaveOrUpdate(new BannerLog
                    {
                        Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
                        Action = BannerAction.View,
                        User = membership.LoggedUser,
                        Banner = banner
                    });
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                var tralala = ex;
            }

            return View(banners);
```

I get this InvalidOperationException:

> The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

It would seem that my model is incorrect, right?

Well, if **I visit** `~/Home/RenderBanners` url, I get partial view with everything rendered correctly **and everything saved** into the database.
It also works with this Action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult FollowBanner(int id)
{
    var banner = bannerRepository.ForcefulGetById(id);

    bannerLogRepository.SaveOrUpdate(new BannerLog
    {
        Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
        Action = BannerAction.Click,
        User = membership.LoggedUser,
        Banner = banner
    });

    return Redirect(banner.Href);
}
```

---

My models:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
}
public class Banner : Entity
{
    //omited
}

public class BannerLog : Entity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public new int Id { get; set; }

    public BannerAction Action { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    public Banner Banner { get; set; }
}

public enum BannerAction
{
    View = 0,
    Click = 1
}
```

ModelBuilder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BannerLog>().HasRequired(x => x.Banner).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
modelBuilder.Entity<BannerLog>().HasOptional(x => x.User).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I believe my models and relations are correct, because it works most of the time... Except when Action gets called through Partial views? What the hell?

EDIT: this project uses repository patern, we have an interface IRepository<T> and Repository<T> implementation of SaveOrUpdate is this:

```
        public virtual T SaveOrUpdate(T entity)
        {
            var casted = entity as Entity;
            if(casted.Id == 0)
                this.Context.Set<T>().Add(entity);

            this.Context.SaveChanges();

            return entity;
        }
```

bannerLogRepository is just Repository<BannerLog>.

Comment: How does the `SaveOrUpdate` method works?

Comment: Updated original question. @Vyacheslav Volkov

Comment: Where do you set ID for `Banner` and `BannerLog`?

Comment: @Bob Banner gets it's ID from database (valid existing number), BannerLog has ID of 0 and if ID == 0, it gets added - EntityFramework (or SQL, dunno) assigns a new ID.

Comment: Whoops, missed the `DatabaseGenerated` part. Have you tried creating your new `BannerLog` as an object before saving it with `SaveOrUpdate` to check if the `BannerLog` object is created properly? i.e. Do the creation of `BannerLog` in two steps 1) Create `BannerLog` 2) `SaveOrUpdate` `BannerLog` object.

Comment: @Bob I tried, all properties are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Since I still have no idea what the hell is going on, I went with a quick hack - instead of doing `@{ Html.RenderAction("RenderBanners", "Home"); }` I just call this Action from JavaScript:

```
<div id="bannerDiv"></div>
<script>
    $("#bannerDiv").load('@Url.Action("RenderBanners", "Home")');
</script>
```

Works fine...